# How to place selected custom arraylist values to same custom arraylist but only up to 3 out of 5

Tags: android, jsonresponse

Here from response i am getting total (getListOfPackages) planlist size 5 it having id numbers 2,3,4,5 and 6, But my requirement i have to display plan id 2,5 and 6 in one recyclerview and remaing in another recyclerview. I am not getting what i want from code please check my code and give solution.
Thanku

```
       List<PlanGsonResponse.ListOfPackages> data=new ArrayList<>();
       ForFamilyList forFamilyList=new ForFamilyList();   
   public void loadData() {
    try {

        PlanGsonRequest planGsonRequest = new      PlanGsonRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.PACKAGES_API, null,
                new Response.Listener<PlanGsonResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PlanGsonResponse res) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (res != null) {
                            data=res.getListOfPackages();

                            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
                            {
                                if (data.get(i).getPackageID()==2||data.get(i).getPackageID()==5||data.get(i).getPackageID()==6)
                                {
                                    forFamilyList.setPackageID(data.get(i).getPackageID());
                                    forFamilyList.setPackageName(data.get(i).getPackageName());
                                    forFamilyList.setAvailableServicesUnderPackage(data.get(i).getAvailableServicesUnderPackage());
                                    forFamilyList.setHealthCheckupsUnderPackage(data.get(i).getHealthCheckupsUnderPackage());
                                    forFamilyList.setPackagePrice(data.get(i).getPackageCost());

                                }
                               forFamilyPackes.add(forFamilyList);


                            }
                            planlistfragmentadapter=new Planlistfragmentadapter(PlanListFragmentNew.this, mContext,forFamilyPackes);
                            mPackagelistRecyclerView.setAdapter(planlistfragmentadapter);

                            String sbid = res.toString();
                            Log.e("arrAY",data.toString());
                            Log.d("hello","hello"+res.getListOfPackages());


                        }  else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError res) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
                , null, PlanGsonResponse.class,
                Request.Priority.IMMEDIATE);
        RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(planGsonRequest);




    } catch(
            Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: here forFamilyPackes is ArrayList for forFamilyList is     List<ForFamilyList> forFamilyPackes=new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please check the ans for data list separation, adapter and recycler
>   views needs to created.

```
List<PlanGsonResponse.ListOfPackages> data=new ArrayList<>();
 List<ForFamilyList> forFamilyPackes1 =new ArrayList<>();
  List<ForFamilyList> forFamilyPackes2 =new ArrayList<>();
   //ForFamilyList forFamilyList=new ForFamilyList(); 

public void loadData() {
   try {

    PlanGsonRequest planGsonRequest = new      PlanGsonRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.PACKAGES_API, null,
            new Response.Listener<PlanGsonResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(PlanGsonResponse res) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (res != null) {
                        data=res.getListOfPackages();

                        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
                        {
 ForFamilyList forFamilyList=new ForFamilyList();
                            if (data.get(i).getPackageID()==2||data.get(i).getPackageID()==5||data.get(i).getPackageID()==6)
                            {

                                forFamilyList.setPackageID(data.get(i).getPackageID());
                                forFamilyList.setPackageName(data.get(i).getPackageName());
                                forFamilyList.setAvailableServicesUnderPackage(data.get(i).getAvailableServicesUnderPackage());
                                forFamilyList.setHealthCheckupsUnderPackage(data.get(i).getHealthCheckupsUnderPackage());
                                forFamilyList.setPackagePrice(data.get(i).getPackageCost());
  forFamilyPackes1.add(forFamilyList);
                            }else
                           forFamilyPackes2.add(forFamilyList);


                        }
  // here make changes for the adapter and recycler views 
                        planlistfragmentadapter=new Planlistfragmentadapter(PlanListFragmentNew.this, mContext,forFamilyPackes1);
                        mPackagelistRecyclerView.setAdapter(planlistfragmentadapter);

                        String sbid = res.toString();
                        Log.e("arrAY",data.toString());
                        Log.d("hello","hello"+res.getListOfPackages());


                    }  else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError res) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
            , null, PlanGsonResponse.class,
            Request.Priority.IMMEDIATE);
    RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(planGsonRequest);




} catch(
        Exception e)

{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanku for your answer, But  id 6 only coming 3 times

Comment: Yes, I updated my code now its working fine Thanku again you save my time.

Comment: WC. Happy to help u.